# Extract string from mixed values

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to extract string from mixed values without any numbers

I succeeded in extract numbers from string by this code .

```
    var tab='#trainingArea13';
    var id=tab.match(/\d+/);//13
```

But I need to extract string without number , what is the best regular expression to add ?

```
  var tabClass=tab.match(/???/);// outpout have to be #trainingArea
```

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: @Tushar
#trainingArea or any string like it , the traget is string without numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
var id=tab.match(/[^0-9]+/);
```

- `[^0-9]`: Not match `0-9` i.e. any number
- `+`     : Match any character one or more times

Comment: What if the string were `#training.area13`? The result would be incorrect: https://regex101.com/r/zN1zZ5/2

Comment: You still have an incorrect explanation in your question, `[.]+` means *1 or more literal dots*. And now, your suggested regex is the same as mine.

Comment: @stribizhev arr! Forgot to remove. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer would be `/[^0-9]+/` regex, because `/[^0-9.]+/` will also exclude a literal dot. The `.` symbol in a character class is treated as a literal.

That said, correct regex is `[^0-9]+` that means *match 1 or more non-digits*.

```js
var tab='#trainingArea13';
var id=tab.match(/[^0-9]+/);
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = id;
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: @AhmadSamilo: Since the original answer was not correct, please reconsider accepted answer.